# Multiple key/value pairs in URL with react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to get multiple pairs of keys/values from the url with react router in a way where the URL scheme would be as follows:

```
/home/:user/key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3
/home/:user/key1/value1/key3/value3
/home/:user/key2/value2/key3/value3/key1/value1
```

Where wouldn't the order matter, because it would just read the value of the next section as the value when it recognizes the key keyword?

So like

```
/ home / 1(user) / sort(key1) / desc(value1) / filter(key2) / friends(value2)
/ home / 1(user) / filter(key1) / friends(value1) / sort(key2) / desc(value2)
```

So that both these URLs would have the same values regardless of order:

```
user == 1 
key1 == value1 
key2 == value2
```

Comment: Take  look at [recursive paths](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/recursive-paths) example